# Throttle limit reached. Retry later

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, geocoder

I apologize in advance for the lack of information on this, I'm at a bit of a loss.
I have a rails 5 API backend, with Postgres database hosted on heroku. It is serving to an iOS client. The main screen in the client is a map which uses the Google API on the front end to draw locations. The backend uses the Geocoder gem to search for places near to the user.
So the front end hits /restaurants and sends user_lat, user_long, search_lat, search_long and distance. The API returns a list of locations that meet those params and the client draws them.

Occasionally the front end displays "Throttle limit reached. Retry Later". This error is supposed to be coming from the back end API but I don't see this error anywhere in the heroku logs.

I've searched the Google API docs, Geocoder gem docs and can't find much. The error doesn't seem to match the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors mentioned in that other users have reported with the Google maps API.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was coming from the RackAttack Gem.